# Is it possible to provide type safety to method decorator options

Tags: typescript, types, decorator, type-safety

I decided to write some utility decorators such as `memoize`, `rateLimiter`. I want to achieve as much type safety as possible without unnecessary boilerplate code.

Is it possible to ensure full type safety in decorators like that without manually specified generics?

```js
type GET_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE<
  T extends TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>
> = T extends TypedPropertyDescriptor<infer U> ? U : never;

interface ITestDecoratorOptions<DECORATED_FUNCTION_ARGUMENTS_TYPE, DECORATED_FUNCTION_RETURN_TYPE> {
  getKeyFromArgs: (args: DECORATED_FUNCTION_ARGUMENTS_TYPE) => string;
  getDefaultValue: (args: DECORATED_FUNCTION_ARGUMENTS_TYPE) => DECORATED_FUNCTION_RETURN_TYPE;
}

const testDecorator = <TYPED_PROPERTY_DESCRIPTOR extends TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>>(
  options: ITestDecoratorOptions<
    Parameters<GET_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE<TYPED_PROPERTY_DESCRIPTOR>>,
    ReturnType<GET_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE<TYPED_PROPERTY_DESCRIPTOR>>
  >
) => {
  return (
    target: Object,
    key: string,
    descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) as PropertyDescriptor
  ): TYPED_PROPERTY_DESCRIPTOR => {
    return null as any;
  };
};

class Test {
  //             \/ Is it possible to remove that generic and keep full type safety here?
  @testDecorator<TypedPropertyDescriptor<(a: number, b: string) => boolean>>({
    getKeyFromArgs: args => {
          // number               string
      return args[0].toString() + args[1]; // full type checking
    },
    getDefaultValue: args => {
      // full type checking: on args(number, string) and return type(boolean)
      if (args[0] === 1) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }
  })
  public someMethod(a: number, b: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2607) in TypeScript, with no obvious solution (other than manually specifying generic type parameters).

The problem with implementing this, as explained in [this comment by @DanielRosenwasser](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2607#issuecomment-168910291) is that using a decorators is like calling a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function, and the kind of generic inference you want would be like this:

```
declare let f: <T>(callback: (x: T) => void) => (y: T) => void;
f(x => x.a)({ a: 100 }); // error!
//     ~ <-- T is inferred as {} or unknown,
```

which doesn't work because TypeScript infers the generic type when the function `f` is invoked on its callback argument, and does not wait until the returned function is itself called.  So by the time the `T` type would actually be known be the compiler, it's too late and it's already failed to infer properly.

I don't know if I have any advice other than to continue to manually specify arguments, and maybe go to that issue in TypeScript and give it a  or describe your use case if you think it's more compelling than the other ones mentioned.  Good luck!